# How to properly use Memcache in web applications with limit and parametric search?

Tags: php, redis, memcached

I'm not sure that my question is initially correct in view of the choice of tool - memcache and perhaps I need to look towards Redis, but as long as my project uses memcache, then the question will be in the context of this tool.

So, I have a project in PHP and there I use memcache something like this:

```php
    public function findById(int $id): Model
    {
        $memcacheKey = md5(implode('', [__METHOD__, $id]));
        
        if ($data = memcache()->get($memcacheKey)) {
            return $data;
        }

        // getting data from db
        $data = ....;

        memcache()->set($memcacheKey, $data, false, 60 * 60 * 24 * 30);

        return $data;
    }
```

```php
   public function findList(array $params): ModelList
    {
        // big sql query use $params array
        $sql = 'SELECT ... LIMIT ...';

        $memcacheKey = md5(implode('', [__METHOD__, serialize($params)]));
        if ($data = memcache()->get($memcacheKey)) {
            return $data;
        }

        // getting data from db use $params array
        $data = ....;

        memcache()->set($memcacheKey, $data, false, 60 * 10);

        return $data;
    }
```

I'm not sure if I'm using caching correctly or effectively.

What to do if one record in the database is updated?
I can manually delete the cache under the key `md5(implode('', ["findById", $id]))` (since I can generate the name of that key) and regenerate the cache for that entry.

But the cache for the list of entries will remain old and it will be updated only after the cache expires.

Where can I read how to solve this problem within memcache?
Is it generally correct to place the result of a parametric search selection in memcache?
Or should I forget about memcache and look towards Redis?

Comment: I would suggest that for the list you not cache anything other than IDs in the list, and then fall back on the `findById()` results. This would stop you from having to invalidate _all_ lists every time you updated the underlying data, as well as prevent you from double-caching entries in both the list and singular caches. Even so, adding/deleting an entry may also invalidate the list depending on your data integrity requirements, so caching lists may be problematic in itself outside of very short TTLs.

Comment: Interesting offer. My understanding is that it should look something like this:

1. Make an SQL query to get a list of identifiers (or get them from memcache).
2. For each of the received identifiers, make one request via findById?

It’s just that if the cache goes bad, then instead of one SQL query for a selection like ``select ... limit 0, 50`` I will have another 50 single queries to the database...

Comment: There is the option of pre-warming the cache in the background as opposed to an entirely pull-through model. Or polling the cache for the IDs that exist and issuing a batched query for the non-existent IDs, eg: `findByIds(array $ids) { ... }`

Comment: @Sammitch Thanks for the advice. 
Now I don't cache lists, I cache only records. The site started working just instantly. There are about 20,000 items in the cache (almost all the records of the site). When deleting an entry, I delete the cache. When changing an entry, I delete it and immediately "warm up" the cache.